# Aggregate values into dynamic intervals with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two spark dataframes with the shape like this:

```
 df1 =
   |  time                   |Value|    
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:36.843 | 1.4 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:36.850 | 1.7 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:37.133 | 1.2 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:37.461 | 1.1 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:37.894 | 1.9 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:38.111 | 2.0 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:39.043 | 2.1 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:39.543 | 1.3 |

df2 =
   |  start time             |  end time               |id |    
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:36.203 | 2020-02-22 04:57:38.570 | 1 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:38.570 | 2020-02-22 04:57:41.173 | 2 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:41.173 | 2020-02-22 04:57:45.461 | 3 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:45.461 | 2020-02-22 04:57:49.094 | 4 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:49.094 | 2020-02-22 04:57:55.221 | 5 |
   | 2020-02-22 04:57:55.221 | 2020-02-22 04:57:60.221 | 6 |
```

I want to build cycles based on the time steps in df2 and aggregate (e.g. mean) the values in df1 through 3 equidistant intervals. For instance in the Cycle with Id 1 between 2020-02-22 04:57:36.203 and 2020-02-22 04:57:38.570, I want to create 3 new columns in df2 with aggregated values of the rows in df 1 whose timestamps belong to one interval in that cycle (cycle duration is varying). My desired output:

```
   |  start time           |  end time              |id | interval1|interval2  | interval3|
   |2020-02-22 04:57:36.203|2020-02-22 04:57:38.570 |1  |   1.55   |  1.15     |    1.95  |
   |2020-02-22 04:57:38.570|2020-02-22 04:57:41.173 |2  | ...
```

How can I get this output?